# I have error Error while connecting to MySQL: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket

Tags: mysql

I have Error:

Error while connecting to MySQL: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2).

And When I restart "Mysql service" My web site fix and good but 2-3 hour later or 5-10 min later retry crash and retry I have error..

Please help me...What is problem and how to I  fix problem?

I use cloud server

Comment: You need to look at your database's log files to figure out why it is stopping.

Comment: This error has caused me a lot of trouble as well. I used the solution at http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/762/solve-cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-tmpmysqlsock/

Comment: How to I open in my server etc files ?